# Application is reopen after picking image from camera or gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I use the below code in order to pick an image from gallery or to open camera.

```
 if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                        } else if (items[item].equals("Upload from camera roll")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
                        } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
```

and this is my `onActivityResult`

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
                CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
                Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
                int scale = 1;
                while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                        && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale *= 2;
                options.inSampleSize = scale;
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);


            }

        }
    }
```

In both of cases (camera or gallery) I am getting the image correctly and I am able to handle the image as I want. My problem is that when the user select an image and press ok then it seems like the application close and open for some seconds. When it opens it is in the last activity and everything works fine. But why my app close and open after picking an image?

I have try to add flags on intent but no luck.

Comment: "But why my app close and open after picking an image?" -- your process may have been terminated to free up system RAM while your app was in the background.

Comment: and what can I do for this?

Comment: Nothing, as things are working as designed. You decided to launch a third-party app. Any time the user switches to another app, your app's process may be terminated to free up system RAM. That's how Android works, and it will happen to your app a lot. If you are concerned about speed, you will need to use profilers and the like to figure out how to speed up your app for the case when its process is terminated and restarted.

Comment: Ok! Now I understand. The problem which I described doesn't appear every time.